# Probability Greatest coefficient

Tags: probability

Question: Silvana rolls a die $50$ times. What is the most likely number of $6$'s she will roll?

I have attempted answering this question by trying to find the greatest coefficient ($T_k+1>T_k$)

The expression I get is $(306-6k)/25k > 1$, which gives $k<9.87$... and $k=9$. However, the answer is $k=8$ ($8$ sixes she is most likely to roll). Is my expression incorrect?

Comment: I don't understand the question. There is a non-zero probability for each of 0, 1, 2, ... , 50 sixes. Do you want to know which of these outcomes has the highest probability?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that we have a Binomial distribution with parameters $p=\frac{1}{6}$, and $n=50$, where $p$ is the exact probability of getting 6 in each roll. And let us name this $X$.

Then, we need to find for what outcome we have the greatest probability. So probability of getting $k$ sixes is: 
$$Pr(X=k)={50 \choose k} (\frac{1}{6})^{k} (\frac{5}{6})^{50-k}. $$

And from here we can see that function is rising till ~8, and then dropping down, so the maximum is for $k=8$.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your calculation. Nor is the question entirely clear...I take it to mean "let $p_k$ be the probability of throwing exactly $k$ $6s$.  For which $k$ is $p_k$ the greatest?"

There are $6^{50}$ ways in total to throw the die $50$ times, keeping track of the order.  In order to throw exactly $k$ $6s$ you have to choose $k$ slots (there are $\binom {50}{k}$ ways to do that) and then the remaining $(50-k)$ slots can be occupied by any tosses of a $5$ sided die, hence there are $5^{50-k}$ ways to fill the other slots.  It follows that the probability $p_k$ of throwing exactly $k$ $6s$ is $$p_k=\binom {50}{k} \frac {5^{50-k}}{6^{50}}$$  A simple computer check shows that this peaks at $k=8$, with $p_7= 0.140489974$, $p_8=0.151026722$ and $p_9=0.140958274$.